# How do I check whether a particular code is in pageable or not through programming(Using static analysis method)

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

Using any static code analysis tool or through coding method I want to check whether a particular code/function and all its calling functions is in pageable or non-pageable.

I am trying to achieve it by doing modifications to any of the open source tool and achieve the above mentioned objective.

Went through msdn, there are certain levels of operation for the PAGED_Macro but couldn't get much information how to achieve this.

I am totally newbie any help or sugggestions would be grateful to you.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're confusing 2 separate concepts. The `PAGED_CODE()` macro verifies that the code is being executed at a level that allows paging (`IRQL <= APC_LEVEL`). It doesn't mean that the containing code resides in paged memory. Execution level can't be verified by static tools since it's a dynamic runtime setting.

By default all the code resides in a non-paged memory. There are preprocessor directives that can be used to put pieces of code in a specified segments, which in turn can be defined as pageable or non-pageable. You can find documentation on this topic at [Making Driver Code or Data Pageable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).